# how to convert HTML to .docx using docx4j?

Tags: java, html, converters, docx, docx4j

I read some articles about the conversion of `html` to `.docx` and I found out that `docx4j` gives pretty decent results. I wonder if anyone could provide me the following info:

1. Needed `jars` and versions.
2. Sample code for conversion from `html` to `.docx`.

Sorry I couldn't post anything I tried because I haven't tried anything on this task yet, although I use `Apache POI` to convert the `bytes[]` I get from `datatabse` to `html` to output in a `rich text editor` on a `jsf` application. Please enlighten me, I'm lost in stress and confusion...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To import XHTML, use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See further http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2013/11/docx4j-3-0-and-maven/

For sample code, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples

Note that your input needs to be well-formed XML, so if you have HTML, you'll need to tidy it first (with one of the many java libraries which can do this for you).

Comment: i tried this and i get this error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/org/xhtmlrenderer/render/Box

Comment: That would suggest you didn't add the jar to your classpath successfully!

Comment: true, the problem is I'm using the IDE project not maven feature, so i can't get all the working versions of the dependencies :/ please help ?

Comment: Which IDE?  You can download http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_0.zip

Comment: yes yes, i downloaded the zip and its working fine now, thank you.

Comment: i wonder why they down voted me on this question, as you understood me and gave me the perfect answer :)

Comment: Papa_Jay I am getting similar exception. I have following jars in classpath docx4j-3.1.0.jar,docx4j-ImportXHTML-3.0.0.jar,slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar. Can tell me what were the jars you included in classpath ?

Comment: You should probably create your own question, but you maybe missing <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId><artifactId>xhtmlrenderer</artifactId>.  Unless you know what you are doing, its best to include all dependencies.

Comment: check full code : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41937582/1406510