# Convert HTML to DOCX

Tags: java, docx4j

My question is very specific and I hope that someone has done this conversion from HTMLto DOCX.

To do this I took a sample code from github and tried it in my local Eclipse Setup.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.NumberingDefinitionsPart;

public class HtmlToDocConvert {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws JAXBException
     * @throws Docx4JException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
            JAXBException, Docx4JException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // File file = new File("C:\\TestWordToHtml\\html\\Test.html");

        String inputfilepath = "C:\\TestWordToHtml\\html\\Test.html";

        try {

            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                    .createPackage();

            NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
            ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();

            XHTMLImporterImpl xHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(
                    wordMLPackage);
            xHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(
                    xHTMLImporter.convert(new File(inputfilepath), null));

            File output = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + "/html_output.docx");
            wordMLPackage.save(output);
            System.out.println("done");

            System.out.println("file path where it is stored is" + " "
                    + output.getAbsolutePath());

        }

        catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Above code is giving me an error as follows

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.docx.DocxRenderer.(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.getRenderer(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:252)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.convert(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:466)
    at HtmlToDocConvert.main(HtmlToDocConvert.java:41)

Jars in my projects to achieve this are as following.

> docx4j-3.2.1.jar
>    docx4j-ImportXHTML-3.2.1.jar
>    slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
>    slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar
>    xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0.jar
>    log4j.jar

I have stripped the xhtmlrendere.jar file to view DOCRendered class and saw that there was no init method inside it.I have spent close to half a day to figure out this thing and I am not sure if this is correct way to do the conversion or this is even possible.

If someone has done this can he/she sent me correct **xhtmlrenderer.jar** file or anypother dependency to achieve this simple task.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Bhanu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert html to doc in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403356/convert-html-to-doc-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

This is not the complete example, is it? Just take a look at [ConvertInXHTMLFile.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFile.java) from [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html) examples.

IMHO you are missing basic parts of the procedure. Furthermore, this topic has been discussed already:

[Convert html to doc in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403356/convert-html-to-doc-in-java)

[How to convert HTML to a Microsoft Word document ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019901/how-to-convert-html-to-a-microsoft-word-document)

[Convert HTML to Microsoft Word Document in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032122/convert-html-to-microsoft-word-document-in-java)

[how to convert HTML to .docx using docx4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461239/how-to-convert-html-to-docx-using-docx4j)

Comment: In case it is not clear, you can find the correct xhtmlrenderer-3.0.0.jar in http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_2_0/optional/ImportXHTML/ or via Maven https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: i was able to get this working after putting latest xhtmlrender-3.0.0. jar in build path.

Answer (score 0):

check [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41937582/1406510). Api used is docx4j-ImportXHTML. Code is simple to follow. Just pass on your xhtml to api as in code and it will do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Replace your xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0 jar file with version 3.0.0 .
[This is Maven Repository link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/xhtmlrenderer/3.0.0)